# How to smooth a classified raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, filter, average, r.neighbor

In QGIS 3.0.2, I want to smooth a reclassified raster layer by `r.neighbor` tool. In this process I use `average` operation. The raster layer created from this tool is empty. I tested this process with `maximum` operation and the answer was correct. I tested `average` operation by both `float` and `int` type of raster layer but there was same empty layer as result.

Comment: QGIS 3.0 is still in early release, so you may be encountering a bug. Try running the same process in 2.18. If it runs without any problem in the earlier version, please make a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org